# What causes websites to suddenly fail to load, then load immediately after a refresh?

Tags: networking, router, switch

I am wondering if there is an issue with the networking in my house.  There are times where websites will fail to load (loading bar gets stuck at around 20%).  After a few seconds, I hit the refresh button and it loads instantly.

I have already restarted my modem, routers and switch a couple times with no success.  I have two Eero routers and a Netgear switch.  Both wired and wireless connections have this problem.  And it is across computers, phones and tablets.

Is there a technical term for when this "stuck loading" happens?

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to know the cause of the issue without more testing.  However, since it occurs on all devices, wired and wireless, its most likely not the devices themselves.

It definitely sounds like a HTTP request is not getting a response and the page is waiting to load.  When you hit refresh, the majority of the page is already in cache and the failing response isnt being requested at that time.

The first thing I would do is eliminate some variables.  Hook a computer directly to the modem and see if the problem persists.  If it still exists, the problem comes from somewhere on the internet to your modem.  However, modems are typically dumb devices, so I doubt that is the problem.  If the problem stops, that points to your router or switch.  Switches are dumb devices, so it would be your router.  You might want to check your router's settings for the cause, or do a factory reset.

You could ask your ISP to take a look, but your luck my vary with ISP tech support.

If you truly want to know whats going on, use a protocol analyzer like [Telerik Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).  However, this is not a tool for novices, but you might be able to muddle your way through it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this issue occurs when there is failure in HTTP request, after re-loading means refreshing the tab it automatically opens because HTTP server request completed successfully this time.